# AWS Cognito - get user's sub in Lambda Trigger function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Does someone know if it is possible in aws Cognito to get the user's 'sub' in one of the [Lambda Trigger functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) you can use?
(especially in *Pre Sign-Up* or *Post Confirmation*)

Since it is recommended to use the 'sub' attribute as primary key it would be great to have access to it.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to do a log on the incoming attributes to the trigger lambda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to this file for event [structs](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/02a038f1708ade8d5fd6a28ee309c388008fe770/events/cognito.go). It's in golang, however, the same struct should be there for other languages.

Then you can retrieve the `sub` attribute from `userAttributes` object. Other fields (e.g. cognito:user_status, email, email_verified, name) could be used based on your requirement.